# Help me identify bass guitar

Tags: fretless-bass-guitar

Man who sold me this fretless bass in Kyiv Ukraine hadn't known anything about its origin. He just said that it's a custom bass from USA. I haven't found anything about this  manufacturer. Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m not familiar with Denis Bass so I’ll only comment. It looks like a well made Fender style instrument, more likely assembled from parts than hand made like the headstock says. I wouldn’t have used a 3 piece body for a natural finish but it looks good. It has some nice details like a satin finish, the brand inlay on the fingerboard, wood fret lines, rear routing, EMG electrionics, ferrules for the neck mount and a sturdy through body bridge.  If it plays and sounds good and you got a decent deal on it keep researching if you like but more importantly play and enjoy it!

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy What if that's custom inlay requested by someone named Dani and the brand is "H" or "HK", which could stand for Hermann Kempf.

Comment: @ToddWilcox It’s possible, I searched “Dani Bass” and “H” basses and found nothing but I didn’t put together the “K” as part of the brand on the headstock. Most of the Kampf basses I saw online have a different style to them though. My main point was if it’s a nice bass, play and enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

Spelling Denis with only one "n" points to France. It could be a one-off bass build by the French guitar builder who goes by the name of Denis Guitare.
There's contact info on his facebook page, so you can ask him whether he built it: https://www.facebook.com/DenisGuitares/

Comment: it is a normal alternatively spelling for Anglo folks of a certain age also.